# git pull doesn't see recent changes

Tags: git, git-pull

I am trying to pull a recent commit from a remote repository with git but it does not see the changes. This is the output from the local server where I am trying to pull to:

```
[root@app-dev ansible]# git pull
Already up-to-date.

[root@app-dev ansible]# git log --pretty=oneline
96f7b87b2a433cf2182909b0e8238378169112a9 Fixed Plesk init_conf issues
2c4145615af4f24f265eadfa729a4b5a84d01afd Initial commit

[root@app-dev ansible]# git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

[root@app-dev ansible]# git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: http://dev.domain.com/ansible/.git
  Push  URL: http://dev.domain.com/ansible/.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

On the remote repository:

```
[root@www ansible]# git log --pretty=oneline
9aef656c5800cb4f5d46270934899994eabe1580 Added readme file - TEST
96f7b87b2a433cf2182909b0e8238378169112a9 Fixed Plesk init_conf issues
2c4145615af4f24f265eadfa729a4b5a84d01afd Initial commit
```

So the remote repository has one more commit which the local one is not seeing when running a `git pull`.

**Update:**

Running `git fetch --force && git reset --hard origin/master` on the local repository returns this (still not the most recent commit):

```
[root@app-dev ansible]# git fetch --force && git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 96f7b87 Fixed Plesk init_conf issues
```

Running `git status` on remote repo:

```
[root@www ansible]# git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       playbook.zip
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the local to pull the most recent version from the remote repo?

Comment: Are the ‘missing’ changes in the same branch as the one you have currently checked out? Does `git fetch; git log --all` show anything more?

Comment: Yes, they are both on the same 'master' branch. The `git fetch; git log --all` command just lists the two commits (not the third missing one).

Comment: @Chris does `git fetch --force && git reset --hard origin/master` help at all?

Comment: Have added output of this command to the question - still the same commit being used, not the most recent one available.

Comment: So your remote repo is not bare? And just to confirm, can you post the output from `git status` run on that remote repo?

Comment: Remote repo is not bare. Just added output of `git status` from the remote repository to the question.

Comment: I see that your remote URLs are via http. Are you sure that the http server is definitely using the same git repository as the one you are issuing the remote commands on?

Comment: If you `git clone http://dev.domain.com/ansible/.git` somewhere else, do you get the same commits or all of them?

Comment: @joran I just cloned as you suggested, and it only has the 2 commits (not 3). So seems something on the remote repo is not making the most recent commit available. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you push anything (a small and non-vital change) to the remote and verify that you are using the right remote repo?

Comment: @joran The remote is via _http://_ so I can't push to it (as far as i'm aware). Are there any other options?